# People Picker suggesting account but still no exact match

Tags: 2010, people-picker, user-accounts

I just setup my farm and have the generic admin account and a john.doe user account for me. I am trying to add my account john.doe as the admin for a new site collection or add myself to anything site, list, etc. When I add john.doe to the people picker it finds nothing. When I add john and click check names it returns John Doe but still does not recognize. Why would it be suggesting the full name of the user account but not recognize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you open up stsadm and do the following:

```
stsadm -o adduser -url http://yoursitecollectionurl.com -userlogin domain\UserName -group SharePointGroup -useremail UserName@domain.com -username UserName
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-sp-latn/sharepointcustomization/thread/48a9ee54-d330-4ca6-bc51-227276ce9934

**EDIT**

Ok no problem! the way people picker work is that it only searches the domain that its being used on! So if you have two domains (pilot1 and pilot2). On pilot1 you have user1 and user2 then on pilot1 using peoplepicker you can only see those two and the same goes for pilot2. The reason behind this is sharepoint is set to search by default on the domain that your on!

as above you will need to use stsadm again but this time we will tell it to search all domains. You need the following command line:

```
STSADM -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker -searchadforests -pv -url
```

Obviously you need to change it so that it reflects your setup, as an example I will carry on with the above:

```
STSADM -o setproperty -pv -pn "peoplepicker -searchadforests" pv "pilot1:pilot2.com -url "http://pilot:201"
```

most is kept the same what changes is you stating that you want to change people picker to add whats in pilot2 into pilot1 and the url is the server name and port numbe, if you have https then just add the "s" so it looks like this: `"https://pilot:201"`

This should solve your issue and make the checking of the names work. Iv added some links for you that go into detail :)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263318.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(office.12).aspx

http://jonnytreesonline.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/sharepoint-people-picker-returning-no.html

Comment: I thought this worked. It adds a new user to the site and group specified. User is still not findable through the people picker for use on other parts of the site.

Comment: iv edited my post to reflect the changes :)